# porque descarga el reporte vacio

Tags: mvc, xml, odoo, report

En el popup que estoy editando ya me descarga los reportes pero los descarga sin información apesar de que en el modelo use un abstractmodel para que me pintara cierta información pero al llenar la vista del modelo y descarga el reporte los descarga vacíos

Adjunto código del modelo:

```
import json
 import io
from xlsxwriter import workbook

  from odoo.tools import date_utils
   from odoo import fields, models, api
   from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError

try:
from odoo.tools.misc import xlsxwriter
except ImportError:
import xlsxwriter


class SaleReportAdvance(models.TransientModel):
_name = "sale_report_general"


date_order = fields.Date(string="Fecha de cotizacion")
validity_date = fields.Date(string='Vencimiento')


def get_ventas_report(self):
   data = {
    'date_order': self.date_order,
    'validity_date': self.validity_date
 }
   return self.env.ref('sale_report_terrestre.action_general_report').report_action(self, data=data)


class generalcard(models.AbstractModel):
_name = 'report_sales'

@api.model
def _get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
    return {
        'doc:ids': docids,
        'doc_model': 'sale.order',
        'docs': self.env['sale.order'].search_read([('date_order', '==', data['date_order']),
                                                    ('validity_date', '==', data['validity_date'])],
                                                   ['name', 'partner_id', 'date_order', 'validity_date',
                                                    'consignee_id', 'country_arrival', "freight_type",
                                                    "gross_weight", "volume", "invoice_amount_assured",
                                                    "freight_assured"])
    }
```

esa es la estructura del modelo de python como va abstraer informacion de otro modelo por eso le di esa estrcutura

Adjunto codigo del reporte:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <odoo>
   <template id="references_report_view">
     <t t-call="web.html_container">
       <div class="header" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
              <h3 class="text-center">Sales Reference Numbers
                <span style="font-size: 14px;"><storng>From</storng>:<t t- 
         esc="from_date"/> <strong>To</strong>: <t t-esc="to_date"/></span>
           </h3>
           <div class="article mt0 o_report_layout_standard">
               <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                   <thead>
                       <th style="wuth:30%">Date</th>
                       <th class="text-center" stlye="width: 10%">Folio</th>
                       <th class="text-center" stlye="width: 10%">Guia</th>
                       <th class="text-center" stlye="width: 10%">Clientw</th>
                       <th class="text-center" stlye="width: 10%">Origen</th>
                       <th class="text-center" stlye="width: 10%">Destino</th>
                       <th class="text-center" stlye="width: 10%">Factura</th>
                       <th class="text-center" stlye="width: 10%">Factura 
                   Asegurada</th>
                       <th class="text-center" stlye="width: 10%">Ejecutivo</th>
                   </thead>
                   <t t-foreach="data" t-as="d">
                       <tr>
                           <td><span t-esc="d['from_date']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['name']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['otro_operation_type']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['partner_id']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['country_departure']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['country_arrival']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['invoice_assured']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['invoice_assured']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['seller_id']"/></td>
                       </tr>
                   </t>
               </table>
           </div>
           <div class="footer o_standard_footer" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
               <div class="row text-center">
                   <div class="col col-12 text-center">
                       <ul class="list-inline">
                           <li class="list-inline-item">Page:</li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">
                               <span class="page"/>
                           </li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">/</li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">
                               <span class="topage"/>
                           </li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </t>
</template>
</odoo>
```

esa es la estructura que le di al reporte como pueden ver es una estructura diferente a la convencional y como les decia tengo otros dos reportes con la misma estructura todos los descarga pero vacíos y para los tres reportes es la misma estructura solo que con diferente información que puedo hacer en este caso para que la información que estoy abstrayendo la  imprima y no muestra el reporte vacío

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

así es como descarga el reporte y esta bien porque le di un diseño personalizado pero solo me imprime la fecha y los encabezados y el pie de página pero la información que esta abstrayendo del modelo no y en el código de python le puse que abstrajera información de un modelo que si tiene registros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141212/discussion-on-question-by-carlos-baez-porque-descarga-el-reporte-vacio).

Answer (score 1):

Primero revisa que el dominio verdaderamente te esté devolviendo documentos.

```py
@api.model
def _get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
    # Primero genera los documentos
    documentos = self.env['sale.order'].search_read([('date_order', '==', data['date_order']),
                                                    ('validity_date', '==', data['validity_date'])],
                                                   ['name', 'partner_id', 'date_order', 'validity_date',
                                                    'consignee_id', 'country_arrival', "freight_type",
                                                    "gross_weight", "volume", "invoice_amount_assured",
                                                    "freight_assured"])
    

    # Puedes intentar con una de estas dos lineas
    print(documentos)
    _logger.info(documentos)


    return {
        'doc:ids': docids,
        'doc_model': 'sale.order',
        'docs': documentos}
```

## Actualización

El logger ponlo de esta manera para detectarlo:

```py
    _logger.info('################### ENTRAMOS AQUI###########'
    _logger.info(documentos)
    _logger.info('################### SALIMOS AQUI###########'
```